# jQuery reorder XML

Tags: jquery, xml, sorting

Hi I am parsing xml using JQuery but need to revers order it so the first items is last etc. Any ideas how I can achieve this or if it's possible? Just using this code

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "XML/Blog.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
$(xml).find('Blog:eq('+ parseInt(index) +')').each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$($(xml).find(your_selector).reverse()).each(function(){

// whatever

});
```

It's a bit clunky, but it should return an array matching the .find(), reverse the order of that array, and then iterate through it with .each().